# how to send mail the fastest with linux

Tags: linux, bash, email, unix

What is the way of sending the fastest mail? I'm using mailx but the fastest comes in 2 min.

```
mailx -r "from" -s "UNIX OPERATIONS ALARM---->$ipNo1 $subject alarmi hk." "to"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Email is not a real-time communication tool and should not ever be considered as such.
2. The speed of delivery does not really depend on what email client you use, but rather on the relay hosts / mail servers that are on the way between you and the recipient.
3. Your question is not related to programming and therefore has no place here on StackOverflow (there are other places where you can ask for help if you need to find out what causes delay in your email delivery, but SO is not one of them)